# Issues updating/rendering list of states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, setstate

I am newbie to React and am having some trouble dealing with the asynchronous nature while trying to render an updated list of states.

Below is my Flatlist and the screen it’s being called at, respectively.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

function FlatListKg({passeddata}) {
  const Item = ({value, text, bg}) => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={[styles.item, {backgroundColor: bg}]}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{value}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.item, {backgroundColor: bg}]}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
  const renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <Item value={item.value} text={item.text} bg={item.bg} />
  );
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={passeddata}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.index}
    />
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the screen I am rendering from passing a list of the states on 106:

```js
function GamesScreen({usernumber}) {
  const [guessnumber, setguessnumber] = useState('');
  const [message, setmessage] = useState('');
  const [trycounter, settrycounter] = useState(0);
  const [guessnumberlist, setguessnumberlist] = useState([]);
  // const [guessnumberlist, setguessnumberlist] = useState([0]);
  const [messagebg, setmessagebg] = useState('');

  function guessnumberhandler(number) {
    setguessnumber(number);
  }

  function messagehandler(messagetext, messagebgval) {
    setmessage(messagetext);
    setmessagebg(messagebgval);
  }
  function resetmessage() {
    setmessage('');
    setguessnumber('');
    settrycounter('');
  }
  function guessnumberdecider() {
    const intguessnumber = parseInt(guessnumber);

    console.log(intguessnumber);
    console.log(usernumber);
    if (intguessnumber > usernumber) {
      console.log('greater');
      setmessage('Number is greater');
      setmessagebg('yellow');
    } else {
      if (intguessnumber < usernumber) {
        console.log('smaller');
        setmessage('Number is smaller');
        setmessagebg('white');
      } else {
        if (intguessnumber === usernumber) {
          console.log('got it');
          messagehandler('You got it', 'red');
        }
      }
    }
    const addElement = () => {
      var newArray = [
        ...guessnumberlist,
        {value: intguessnumber, text: message, bg: messagebg},
      ];
      setguessnumberlist(newArray);
    };
    addElement();
    settrycounter(trycounter + 1);
    if (trycounter >= 4) {
      messagehandler('Exceeded the number of tries!');
      setmessagebg('red');
    }
  }

  function guessnumberreset() {
    setguessnumber('');
    resetmessage;
  }

  const toastwithMessage = toastmessage => {
    console.log(toastmessage);
    Toast.show({
      type: 'info',
      text2: toastmessage,
      visibilityTime: 6000,
      backgroundColor: '#ddb52f',
    });
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Title>Guess the Number</Title>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.numberInput}
            placeholder="enter guess"
            placeholderTextColor="black"
            maxLength={2}
            keyboardType="number-pad"
            onChangeText={guessnumberhandler}
            value={guessnumber}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.gamebuttoncontainer}>
          <View>
            <PrimaryButton onPress={guessnumberdecider}> Check </PrimaryButton>
          </View>
          <View>
            <PrimaryButton onPress={guessnumberreset}> Reset </PrimaryButton>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.resultscontainer}>
        <FlatListKg passeddata={guessnumberlist} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The issue I have is that for all the three different values of text, bg, flatlist seems to be missing the updated value. it works fine for the values post first time state change. Below is the state values.

```js
[{
    "name": "State",
    "value": "7",
    "subHooks": [],
    "hookSource": {
      "lineNumber": 112842,
      "functionName": "GamesScreen",
      "fileName": "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.Zenters",
      "columnNumber": 41
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": "Exceeded the number of tries!",
    "subHooks": [],
    "hookSource": {
      "lineNumber": 112847,
      "functionName": "GamesScreen",
      "fileName": "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.Zenters",
      "columnNumber": 42
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": 5,
    "subHooks": [],
    "hookSource": {
      "lineNumber": 112852,
      "functionName": "GamesScreen",
      "fileName": "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.Zenters",
      "columnNumber": 42
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": [
      "{bg: \"\", text: \"\", value: 12}",
      "{bg: \"yellow\", text: \"Number is greater\", value: 14}",
      "{bg: \"yellow\", text: \"Number is greater\", value: 16}",
      "{bg: \"yellow\", text: \"Number is greater\", value: 8}",
      "{bg: \"white\", text: \"Number is smaller\", value: 7}"
    ],
    "subHooks": [],
    "hookSource": {
      "lineNumber": 112857,
      "functionName": "GamesScreen",
      "fileName": "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.Zenters",
      "columnNumber": 42
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": "red",
    "subHooks": [],
    "hookSource": {
      "lineNumber": 112862,
      "functionName": "GamesScreen",
      "fileName": "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.Zenters",
      "columnNumber": 42
    }
  }
]
```

Here is the UI of the output. I think it’s something to do with how I am updating the list and there is a way to make it synchronous or force an update.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this function

```
function guessnumberdecider() {

    const intguessnumber = parseInt(guessnumber);

    let newMessage = '', newMessageBg = '' 

    if (intguessnumber > usernumber) {
      console.log('greater');
      newMessage = 'Number is greater'
      newMessageBg = 'yellow'
    } 
    else if (intguessnumber < usernumber) {
        console.log('smaller');
        newMessage = 'Number is smaller'
        newMessageBg = 'white'
    } 
    else if (intguessnumber === usernumber) {
        newMessage = 'You got it'
        newMessageBg = 'Red'
    }
    
    const element = {
        value: intguessnumber, 
        text: newMessage, 

        bg: newMessageBg
    }

    setguessnumberlist([...guessnumberlist,element])
    setmessage(newMessage);
    setmessagebg(newMessageBg);
    

    settrycounter(trycounter + 1);
    if (trycounter >= 4) {
      messagehandler('Exceeded the number of tries!');
      setmessagebg('red');
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked after i modified 

    const element = {
      value: intguessnumber,
      text: newMessage,
      bg: newMessageBg,
    };

any further readings for this approach or is it generally removing states in values we want to reuse?

Comment: Previously u were using` 
const addElement = () => {
      var newArray = [
        ...guessnumberlist,
        {value: intguessnumber, text: message, bg: messagebg},
      ];
      setguessnumberlist(newArray);
    };
    addElement();
`

which adds element in array but you were using state variables message and messaeBg which were going to update after execution of function. so it takes current values

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what did you change and why? What is the idea/gist?  From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73329843/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).